# Strange integral symbol with beamer

Tags: beamer

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[serif]{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {
  \usetheme{Warsaw}
  % \usecolortheme{lily}
}

\usepackage[minionint,mathlf,textlf]{MinionPro}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{Myriad-LF}
\usepackage{inconsolata}

\DeclareSymbolFont{missing}{OML}{cmr}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\ell}{\mathord}{missing}{'140}

\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Function}
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item[$\bullet$] This function
  \end{enumerate}
    \begin{align}
        A & = \dfrac{1}{a}\int\limits_{-a/2}^{a/2}g(t)dt,
    \end{align}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

which produces the following frame:

[image]

I do not know why the integral sign is strange, looking like an M or a W.

I found these warnings:

```
Class beamer Warning: ``serif'' is obsolete. Use font theme ``serif'' instead on input line 336. 

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape 'TU/MinionPro-LF/m/n' undefined(Font) using 'TU/lmr/m/n' instead on input line 647. 

Package inputenc Warning: inputenc package ignored with utf8 based engines. 

LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.
```

Comment: You're using the wrong font, apparently

Comment: I can't test because I don't have these special fonts, but try with `\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}`

Comment: The `serif` option is deprecated. The log file tells you what to use instead.

Comment: Do you find any error messages or warning in the log file?

Comment: I found these warnings : `Class beamer Warning: ``serif'' is obsolete. Use font theme ``serif'' instead on input line 336.`

`LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape 'TU/MinionPro-LF/m/n' undefined(Font) using 'TU/lmr/m/n' instead on input line 647.`

`Package inputenc Warning: inputenc package ignored with utf8 based engines.`

`LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.`

Comment: also `professionalfonts` did not help.

Comment: removing the option `minionint` fixed the issue, but why? I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

Changing

```
\usepackage[minionint,mathlf,textlf]{MinionPro}
```

to

```
\usepackage[mathlf,textlf]{MinionPro}
```

solved the problem.